# Split Address in Excel Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel column where each cell contains the contents of an address. What I'd like to do is split THE FIRST TWO words into a their own separate columns.

For example:
123 South Bend Rd, Make Belive

Would output:
123 in one cell, South in another.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming data is in column A, use formula in B1 (and copy down for all data rows)

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

and in cell C1

```
=MID(A1,LEN(B1)+2,FIND(" ",A1,LEN(B1)+2)-LEN(B1)-2)
```

Comment: In your first formula it might be worth using `=TRIM()` just to make sure no leading white spaces otherwise it may find a `" "` at start of string.